# the native symfony2 service doctrine.orm.entity_manager does not work in unit test method with phpUnit

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, phpunit

As I mention in the title, when a request the doctrine.orm.entity_manager service from the unit test method, I still get the following error. Notice that I already check that my schema and it db are synchronized and the schema is valid.

my unit test method:

```
public function testOneParByPollingStation()
{
    $statisticsHandler = $this->container->get('...__service_name__...');

    $em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
    $party = $em->getRepository('..:Party')->findOneBy(array('name' => 'NDC'));

    $pollingStations = $em->getRepository('...:PollingStation2')->findAll();
}
```

Error generated when running the Unit testing:

```
PHPUnit 5.1.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

.....E                                                              6 / 6 (100%)

Time: 426 ms, Memory: 17.00Mb

There was 1 error:

1) Iballot\CmsBundle\Test\Component\StatisticsHandlerTest::testOneParByPollingStation
Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\InvalidFieldNameException: An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.issueNumber AS issueNumber_2, t0.preFirstVerifier AS preFirstVerifier_3, t0.parlFirstVerifier AS parlFirstVerifier_4, t0.preEditedVotesProcess AS preEditedVotesProcess_5, t0.parEditedVotesProcess AS parEditedVotesProcess_6, t0.verfierNumber AS verfierNumber_7, t0.registeredVoters AS registeredVoters_8, t0.name AS name_9, t0.verifier_number AS verifier_number_10, t0.address AS address_11, t0.edited_result_id AS edited_result_id_12, t13.id AS id_14, t13.name AS name_15, t13.telephone AS telephone_16, t13.firstName AS firstName_17, t13.lastName AS lastName_18, t13.dob AS dob_19, t13.image AS image_20, t13.gender AS gender_21, t13.polling_station_id AS polling_station_id_22, t0.constituency_id AS constituency_id_23 FROM polling_station2 t0 LEFT JOIN representator t13 ON t13.polling_station_id = t0.id':

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't0.edited_result_id' in 'field list'
```

polling_station2 table description:

```
id
int(11)
NO
PRI
NULL
auto_increment
constituency_id
int(11)
NO
MUL
NULL
preFirstVerifier
tinyint(1)
YES
NULL
parlFirstVerifier
tinyint(1)
YES
NULL
verfierNumber
int(11)
YES
NULL
registeredVoters
int(11)
YES
NULL
name
varchar(255)
NO
NULL
verifier_number
varchar(255)
NO
NULL
address
varchar(255)
NO
NULL
issueNumber
int(11)
YES
NULL
preEditedVotesProcess
tinyint(1)
YES
NULL
parEditedVotesProcess
tinyint(1)
YES
NULL
edited_result_id
int(11)
YES
UNI
NULL
```

Comment: When you're running tests, they get run in the `test` environment. Are your test DB and development databases different? Also, review your definition of the `PollingStation2` entity.

Comment: I just have one database both for testing and for development and the PollingStation2 entity is correct or what do you suspect ?

Comment: The error clearly states that the field `edited_result_id` does not exist in your DB but is defined in your `PollingStation2` entity. Either the DB state or the entity definition are wrong.

Comment: Looks like your database schema is not up to date with your `PollingStation2` mapping settings

Comment: Of course it is ! because I check it and that is why said it in the post.

Comment: Update your question with the results of 'describe polling_station2'.  The error message clearly indicates that the column called edited_result_id clearly does not exist.

Comment: ok it's done you can see it